# How to exchange content depending on a boolean?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic4

I want to exchanges some content in my page.html depending if an boolean is true or false. So I've seen that you could create things like this with the `<ng-content>`but somehow this didn't work out. I get this error: `Error: Template parse errors: <ng-content> element cannot have content.` I also notice that there has to be some way to delete the old content.

page.html

```
      <ion-card>
    <!--  content to move away when bool true-->
        </ion-card>

    <div *ngIf="!checked">
    <ng-content>
      <ion-card>
<!-- new content when bool false-->
</ion-card>
    </ng-content> 
      </div>
```

Comment: What's your purpose in using ng-content? I think doing away with ng-content your code should work fine.

Comment: ngif should take care of showing content based on boolean. No need of ng-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would having two separate conditionals work for you?

```html
<ion-card *ngIf="checked">
    <!--  content to move away when bool true-->
</ion-card>

<ion-card *ngIf="!checked">
    <!-- new content when bool false-->
</ion-card>
```

If that does not work, you could use a *switch*

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="checked">
    <ion-card *ngSwitchCase="true">
        <!--  content to move away when bool true-->
    </ion-card>
    <ion-card *ngSwitchCase="false">
        <!-- new content when bool false-->
    </ion-card>
</div>
```

Comment: is there actually anything I can do, when using that in a list that the transitions looks better. Since the next element is always pushed up and down again quickly before the element is loaded.

Comment: @ColinRagnarök Have you tried adding some css transitions? I am not sure how you are displaying the information. You could also display a loadingCtrl while you are waiting for the data to be ready and then generate the UI, if the elements are, or are not, there when the page gets generated they won't get pushed up and down.